# jquery mobile append does not work

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I am using jquery mobile to develop an android app and i had this code to append some data retrieved on an ajax call as a list..
a portion in head here..

```
var datatoinsert = "<ul data-role=\"listview\"><li>Faculty ID: "+  $.urlParam('id') + "</li><li>Name: "+data.name + "</li><li>Phone : "+
                                             data.phonenumber +"</li><li>Faculty Since :" + data.since + "</li><li> Qualification :" + data.qual + "</li></ul>"; 

alert(datatoinsert);
  (".content").append(datatoinsert);
```

It was to insert the data to a div in body..

```
<div class= "content" data-role="content">

        </div>
```

But it fails to do so, the alert works quite fine.. and i see that i get all the data required.. but it doesnt seem to show up on screen. any thing I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, You have missed `$` before `(".content")`

```
 $(".content").append(datatoinsert);
```

OR

```
$(".content").html(datatoinsert);
```

Comment: oh god.. That was so careless from my side.. Thanks a lot.. Also can you tell me when i fixed it, the listview looks a bit old fashioned. no the jquery style.. you know why?

Comment: What you mean `old fashioned` ? can you explain more about.

Comment: got it. .trigger('create') did the trick! Thanx for wasting time on me!