# Jquery appendTo() not working on Chrome Android

Tags: android, jquery, html, google-chrome

I've developed a search function that gets an element from a `div` and shows it on a results `div` while typing on a textbox, you can see it here: http://elcostal.co/index.php/productos/fyv

```
$("#searchbox").on('change keyup paste', function() {
    var texto = $("#searchbox").val(); 
    if (texto.length < 3) {
        $("[id^=" + texto + "]").appendTo("#prods");
        $("#results").empty();   
    }
    else if (texto.length == 3) {
        $("[id^=" + texto + "]").appendTo("#results");  
    }
});
```

If you try on desktop Chrome it works as expected but on Android Chrome, nothing happens. Other browsers, no idea.

I also tried this: [jquery mobile append does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21214520/jquery-mobile-append-does-not-work)
and this:

```
$('#jobStream').hide();
$('#jobStream').get(0).offsetHeight;
$('#jobStream').show();
```

but no luck.